# Is it possible for me to run Python OpenCV on Flutter

Tags: flutter, opencv, dart

I am currently developing an app using Flutter and would like to use OpenCV-related scripts to read (OMR).
Is it possible for me to run Python OpenCV (.py) in Flutter and by running multiple devices at the same time and is production server.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, You can use [OPEN_CV](https://pub.dev/packages/opencv_4) library for android and iOS devices.

**OR**

You can use [chaquopy](https://pub.dev/packages/chaquopy) for custom scripts in python for android only devices.